# Can a Web Deployment Project support quiet installation

Tags: .net, asp.net, windows-installer, web-deployment-project

I need to install a web deployment fromn a quiet installation and pass in the web directory, installation directory etc.  I know that the values of the MSI are available to a custom action, but my experience is that in quiet mode these get overwritten by the default value on the GUI even when in quiet mode.

Am I wrong on this assumption (or indeed is there a setting I've missed to stop this behaviour?), or is there another way to support the installation using quiet and passing in parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw5hzsah.aspx) which actually has the information I needed.

For anyone else who needs it, the default overwrite behaviour of properties in the MSI has been fixed for the three web MSI properties which are:

1. TARGETVDIR - Vdir name
2. TARGETAPPPOOL - App pool name
3. TARGETSITE - IIS Metabase name of the site.